# C# List.Clear() clearing ALL Lists

Tags: c#, list

I'm loosing my head on this one.  I have two lists.  When I clear one list, both lists are Cleared!  I cannot find out where or why this is happening.

Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("A: {0} \t As: {1}", Globals.Artists.Count(), Globals.ArtistsSelected.Count);
Globals.ArtistsSelected.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("A: {0} \t As: {1}", Globals.Artists.Count(), Globals.ArtistsSelected.Count);
```

The results from the above code is:

```
A: 121   As: 121
A: 0     As: 0
```

As you can see before the clear, Artists and ArtistsSelected both have 121 items. When I clear the one, the other one is cleared too.

Here is how the lists are declared:

```
public static List<string> Artists = new List<string>();
public static List<string> ArtistsSelected = new List<string>();
```

I only have one place that loads Artists and it doesn't get called again after that point, and No place at all looks like this:
`Artists = ArtistsSelected;` or this: `Artists.Clear()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!   Oh, I also tried renaming `ArtistsSelected` to something like `SelectedArtists` and it still didn't phase it.`

*** UPDATE ***

Because some of you are asking, here is how Artists is loaded by calling:

```
public static void populateArtistList()
    {
        Globals.Artists = SQL_Read.getArtistList();
        Globals.SelectedArtists = Globals.Artists;
    }
```

Then here's the SQL part:

```
public static List<string> getArtistList()
    {
        List<string> artists = new List<string>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string query = "SELECT Name FROM Artists ";

        con.ConnectionString = SQL_getConnectionString.conStr();
        con.Open();

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            artists.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }

        con.Close();
        return artists;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use `Count` for `ArtistsSelected` and `Count()` for `Artists`?

Comment: @Abion47 - Good catch.  that was left over from other code.  I removed the `Count()` with just `Count`.  Same problem

Comment: It would be helpful in this case to see more of the Globals class. At some point in your code, Artists and ArtistsSelected must be getting set to the same reference.

Comment: How did you load Artists?

Comment: I load Artists from my SQL DB with a list of all the artists in my collection.  At that point I make selected equal to Artist `ArtistsSelected = Artists;`.  After that I can go through aprocess where I can deselect some of the Artists I want to process and save those in the ArtistsSelected  -  leaving Artists untouched for further coding.

Comment: `ArtistsSelected = Artists;` makes both fields point to the same instance.

Comment: @Klinger  You may be on to something!  I need to pass the values not reference... okay, back to Google!

Comment: @KerryWhite just replace with Globals.SelectedArtists = Globals.Artists.ToList()

Comment: @Martheen  I tried this and it worked:  'Globals.SelectedArtists = new List<string>(Globals.Artists);'

Comment: @Martheen I tried your way too and it worked as well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Globals.SelectedArtists = Globals.Artists;` is your culprit.

Doing so makes both fields point to the same list instance.

What you need to do is the following:

`Globals.SelectedArtists.AddRange(Globals.Artists);`

Comment: Got it!   `Globals.SelectedArtists = new List<string>(Globals.Artists);'

Comment: @KerryWhite That works too, but you are replacing the original object. In any case, exposing a list as a global like that can lead to some interesting problems.

Comment: I tried your way as well, it seems to work too.  I don't like replacing the original object, so I'll stick to your way or Martheen's way (above).  Thanks again!

Comment: @KerryWhite Actually my method also replace the original object. I believe it's identical to List<string>(Globals.Artists) even